# Anonymous Inner Class - Collections sort

Tags: java

I am creating a Comparator as Anonymous inner class and I am not sure if its the best approach. I am creating it only once in my code, but what I am not sure is whether that inner class is created each time I am sorting a list. For example in an application if I am calling the sort method using that comparator 10 times, would there be ten extra classes created?

```
Collections.sort(originalList, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        int value1 = o1.getPropertyCode().compareTo(o2.getPropertyCode());
        if (value1 == 0) {
            int value2=o1.getPropertyValue().compareTo(o2.getPropertyValue());
            return value2;
        }
        return value1;
    }
});
```

vs

Collections.sort(originalList, new SomeComparator());

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words! Show us it!

Comment: if by "be ten extra classes created" you mean 10 instances, then the answer is yes. (that's what the `new` keyword does)

Comment: ...but do those 10 extra instances *actually* have a noticeable effect on performance? Under specific circumstances, maybe; generally, nah.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714602/anonymous-vs-named-inner-classes-best-practices?rq=1 could shed some light

Comment: Coded added, I am sorting by two variables,.

Comment: @AndyTurner : Extra instances or extra implementation classes?

Comment: @user2296988 if you mean that you've got 10 different anonymous classes, do you think that makes a difference either? Once they're loaded by the class loader, it's just creating instances.

Comment: This is similar question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995101/inline-comparator-vs-custom-comparator-in-java

Comment: @MrSimpleMind : Similar, not identical, thanks

Comment: @AndyTurner : Thanks, then it means its does nt make any difference as, Anonymous class or not, same number of  instances will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous classes are turned into a regular class definition by the compiler and are actually given a name like `OutterClass$1`, you can not refer to that class by that name but you can do for example `new Object() {}.class.getName()` to see that it's always the same. Whenever your code hits the line in question it's using just 1 class - whether you give it an explicit name or not. Your 2 options are basically the same.

But when you read your line of code up until `Collections.sort(originalList, new` you should be aware that that `new` creates a new instance (not a class) every time. I.e. it allocates memory, initializes the thing, .. none of which is needed more than once because the created comparator object will never differ.

What you'll want to do is either storing the created comparator once in a field like so (or like in Java's own source [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.0CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))

```
private static final Comparator<User> USER_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        int value1 = o1.getPropertyCode().compareTo(o2.getPropertyCode());
        if (value1 == 0) {
            int value2=o1.getPropertyValue().compareTo(o2.getPropertyValue());
            return value2;
        }
        return value1;
    }
};
private void someCode() {
    Collections.sort(originalList, USER_COMPARATOR);
}
```

Or with Java 8 you can turn it into a lambda (notice the missing `new`) which also doesn't create new instances every time

```
Collections.sort(originalList, (o1, o2) -> {
    int value1 = o1.getPropertyCode().compareTo(o2.getPropertyCode());
    if (value1 == 0) {
        int value2=o1.getPropertyValue().compareTo(o2.getPropertyValue());
        return value2;
    }
    return value1;
});
```

Comment: If you're turning it into a lambda, you might as well write the much more compact `comparing(User::getPropertyCode).thenComparing(User::getPropertyValue)`.

Comment: Excellent, did not know about this being used in String class. This should be made more popular, like a design pattern. Not that memory is always a problem with extra classes, but I am sure its helpful in my case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman downside is that this doesn't result in a static-field like lambda but one that gets generated each time that code runs. Probably not after JIT gets its hand on it.. but anyways I'd assign it to a static field in that case

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have that Comparator in a method, then at each call a new one will be instantiated. Moreover, that Comparator will contain a reference to the encompassing class.

On the other hand, if you define that anonymous inner class as a static field, then there will be only one (per class loader).

Comment: How do I declare it as a static field? Like a static initilization block?